# Do things with specific part of array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am not sure about foreach, maybe I need to create new "Bob array"?

```
string[] array = new string[] {"Andrew 11312", "23214 Bob", "123 John", "Bob 222"}
foreach (var i /*which contains "Bob" */ in array)
{do things}
```

Comment: Do you need to update the values in the array or just perform an action?

Comment: No, i dont need to edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ to achieve this.

```
foreach (var bob in array.Where(i => i.Contains("Bob")))
{
    // Do stuff with Bob ...
}
```

This requires the following namespace: `using System.Linq;`

If you need to modify the parts that contain `"Bob"` then you can do it with `Select()`.

```
 array = array.Select((i) =>
 {
     if (i.Contains("Bob"))
     {
         // Modify i, because it contains "Bob"
     }

     return i;
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, its not just Bob, John, etc. I edited my code.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
{
    String s = array[i];

    if (!s.Contains("Bob"))
        continue;

    // do what you have to do...
}
```

Or, as well:

```
foreach (String s in array)
{
    if (!s.Contains("Bob"))
        continue;

    // do what you have to do...
}
```